# C++ class creation "does not name a type" (using arduino and color sensor)

Tags: c++, arduino

I've browsed over other questions and I couldn't really find anything that could help me out.  I'm still really new with Arduino and haven't used the C language in a few years so I am a but rusty...

My issue is initializing the class variable "tcs"  in my main file right after I include all the libraries that I need.  It is giving me  ""Adafruit_TCS34725" does not name a type."

It should be calling the function in my parent class that was included to initialize the variable, correct??

Also, bear in mind that I am unable to test/debug the rest of the code so don't hate if there are any errors in that as well :P  I've included the main file and the 2 libraries I've added in.

Here is main c file used to run the Arduino.
Main.h

```
#include <Adafruit_TCS34725.h>
#include <Adafruit_TCS34725_CPP.h>
#include <Servo.h>
#include <Wire.h>

/* Initialise with default values (int time = 2.4ms, gain = 1x) */
Adafruit_TCS34725 tcs = Adafruit_TCS34725();

/* Initialise with specific int time and gain values */
Adafruit_TCS34725 tcs = Adafruit_TCS34725(TCS34725_INTEGRATIONTIME_700MS, TCS34725_GAIN_1X);

void setup(void) {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  if (tcs.begin()) {
    Serial.println("Found sensor");
  } else {
    Serial.println("No TCS34725 found ... check your connections");
    while (1);
  }

  // Now we're ready to get readings!
}

void loop(void) {
  uint16_t r, g, b, c, colorTemp, lux;

  tcs.getRawData(&r, &g, &b, &c);
  colorTemp = tcs.calculateColorTemperature(r, g, b);
  lux = tcs.calculateLux(r, g, b);

  Serial.print("Color Temp: "); Serial.print(colorTemp, DEC); Serial.print(" K - ");
  Serial.print("Lux: "); Serial.print(lux, DEC); Serial.print(" - ");
  Serial.print("R: "); Serial.print(r, DEC); Serial.print(" ");
  Serial.print("G: "); Serial.print(g, DEC); Serial.print(" ");
  Serial.print("B: "); Serial.print(b, DEC); Serial.print(" ");
  Serial.print("C: "); Serial.print(c, DEC); Serial.print(" ");
  Serial.println(" ");
}
```

Here is the header file
Adafruit_TCS34725.h

```
/**************************************************************************/
/*! 
    @file     Adafruit_TCS34725.h
    @author   KTOWN (Adafruit Industries)


    @section LICENSE


    Software License Agreement (BSD License)


    Copyright (c) 2013, Adafruit Industries
    All rights reserved.


    Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
    modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions are met:
    1. Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright
    notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
    2. Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
    notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the
    documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
    3. Neither the name of the copyright holders nor the
    names of its contributors may be used to endorse or promote products
    derived from this software without specific prior written permission.


    THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS ''AS IS'' AND ANY
    EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED
    WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE
    DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT HOLDER BE LIABLE FOR ANY
    DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES
    (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES;
    LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND
    ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT
    (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS
    SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
*/
/**************************************************************************/
#ifndef _TCS34725_H_
#define _TCS34725_H_


#if ARDUINO >= 100
 #include <Arduino.h>
#else
 #include <WProgram.h>
#endif


#include <Wire.h>


#define TCS34725_ADDRESS          (0x29)


#define TCS34725_COMMAND_BIT      (0x80)


#define TCS34725_ENABLE           (0x00)
#define TCS34725_ENABLE_AIEN      (0x10)    /* RGBC Interrupt Enable */
#define TCS34725_ENABLE_WEN       (0x08)    /* Wait enable - Writing 1 activates the wait timer */
#define TCS34725_ENABLE_AEN       (0x02)    /* RGBC Enable - Writing 1 actives the ADC, 0 disables it */
#define TCS34725_ENABLE_PON       (0x01)    /* Power on - Writing 1 activates the internal oscillator, 0 disables it */
#define TCS34725_ATIME            (0x01)    /* Integration time */
#define TCS34725_WTIME            (0x03)    /* Wait time (if TCS34725_ENABLE_WEN is asserted) */
#define TCS34725_WTIME_2_4MS      (0xFF)    /* WLONG0 = 2.4ms   WLONG1 = 0.029s */
#define TCS34725_WTIME_204MS      (0xAB)    /* WLONG0 = 204ms   WLONG1 = 2.45s  */
#define TCS34725_WTIME_614MS      (0x00)    /* WLONG0 = 614ms   WLONG1 = 7.4s   */
#define TCS34725_AILTL            (0x04)    /* Clear channel lower interrupt threshold */
#define TCS34725_AILTH            (0x05)
#define TCS34725_AIHTL            (0x06)    /* Clear channel upper interrupt threshold */
#define TCS34725_AIHTH            (0x07)
#define TCS34725_PERS             (0x0C)    /* Persistence register - basic SW filtering mechanism for interrupts */
#define TCS34725_PERS_NONE        (0b0000)  /* Every RGBC cycle generates an interrupt                                */
#define TCS34725_PERS_1_CYCLE     (0b0001)  /* 1 clean channel value outside threshold range generates an interrupt   */
#define TCS34725_PERS_2_CYCLE     (0b0010)  /* 2 clean channel values outside threshold range generates an interrupt  */
#define TCS34725_PERS_3_CYCLE     (0b0011)  /* 3 clean channel values outside threshold range generates an interrupt  */
#define TCS34725_PERS_5_CYCLE     (0b0100)  /* 5 clean channel values outside threshold range generates an interrupt  */
#define TCS34725_PERS_10_CYCLE    (0b0101)  /* 10 clean channel values outside threshold range generates an interrupt */
#define TCS34725_PERS_15_CYCLE    (0b0110)  /* 15 clean channel values outside threshold range generates an interrupt */
#define TCS34725_PERS_20_CYCLE    (0b0111)  /* 20 clean channel values outside threshold range generates an interrupt */
#define TCS34725_PERS_25_CYCLE    (0b1000)  /* 25 clean channel values outside threshold range generates an interrupt */
#define TCS34725_PERS_30_CYCLE    (0b1001)  /* 30 clean channel values outside threshold range generates an interrupt */
#define TCS34725_PERS_35_CYCLE    (0b1010)  /* 35 clean channel values outside threshold range generates an interrupt */
#define TCS34725_PERS_40_CYCLE    (0b1011)  /* 40 clean channel values outside threshold range generates an interrupt */
#define TCS34725_PERS_45_CYCLE    (0b1100)  /* 45 clean channel values outside threshold range generates an interrupt */
#define TCS34725_PERS_50_CYCLE    (0b1101)  /* 50 clean channel values outside threshold range generates an interrupt */
#define TCS34725_PERS_55_CYCLE    (0b1110)  /* 55 clean channel values outside threshold range generates an interrupt */
#define TCS34725_PERS_60_CYCLE    (0b1111)  /* 60 clean channel values outside threshold range generates an interrupt */
#define TCS34725_CONFIG           (0x0D)
#define TCS34725_CONFIG_WLONG     (0x02)    /* Choose between short and long (12x) wait times via TCS34725_WTIME */
#define TCS34725_CONTROL          (0x0F)    /* Set the gain level for the sensor */
#define TCS34725_ID               (0x12)    /* 0x44 = TCS34721/TCS34725, 0x4D = TCS34723/TCS34727 */
#define TCS34725_STATUS           (0x13)
#define TCS34725_STATUS_AINT      (0x10)    /* RGBC Clean channel interrupt */
#define TCS34725_STATUS_AVALID    (0x01)    /* Indicates that the RGBC channels have completed an integration cycle */
#define TCS34725_CDATAL           (0x14)    /* Clear channel data */
#define TCS34725_CDATAH           (0x15)
#define TCS34725_RDATAL           (0x16)    /* Red channel data */
#define TCS34725_RDATAH           (0x17)
#define TCS34725_GDATAL           (0x18)    /* Green channel data */
#define TCS34725_GDATAH           (0x19)
#define TCS34725_BDATAL           (0x1A)    /* Blue channel data */
#define TCS34725_BDATAH           (0x1B)


typedef enum
{
  TCS34725_INTEGRATIONTIME_2_4MS  = 0xFF,   /**<  2.4ms - 1 cycle    - Max Count: 1024  */
  TCS34725_INTEGRATIONTIME_24MS   = 0xF6,   /**<  24ms  - 10 cycles  - Max Count: 10240 */
  TCS34725_INTEGRATIONTIME_50MS   = 0xEB,   /**<  50ms  - 20 cycles  - Max Count: 20480 */
  TCS34725_INTEGRATIONTIME_101MS  = 0xD5,   /**<  101ms - 42 cycles  - Max Count: 43008 */
  TCS34725_INTEGRATIONTIME_154MS  = 0xC0,   /**<  154ms - 64 cycles  - Max Count: 65535 */
  TCS34725_INTEGRATIONTIME_700MS  = 0x00    /**<  700ms - 256 cycles - Max Count: 65535 */
}
tcs34725IntegrationTime_t;


typedef enum
{
  TCS34725_GAIN_1X                = 0x00,   /**<  No gain  */
  TCS34725_GAIN_4X                = 0x01,   /**<  2x gain  */
  TCS34725_GAIN_16X               = 0x02,   /**<  16x gain */
  TCS34725_GAIN_60X               = 0x03    /**<  60x gain */
}
tcs34725Gain_t;


class Adafruit_TCS34725 {
 public:
  Adafruit_TCS34725(tcs34725IntegrationTime_t = TCS34725_INTEGRATIONTIME_2_4MS, tcs34725Gain_t = TCS34725_GAIN_1X);

  boolean  begin(void);
  void     setIntegrationTime(tcs34725IntegrationTime_t it);
  void     setGain(tcs34725Gain_t gain);
  void     getRawData(uint16_t *r, uint16_t *g, uint16_t *b, uint16_t *c);
  uint16_t calculateColorTemperature(uint16_t r, uint16_t g, uint16_t b);
  uint16_t calculateLux(uint16_t r, uint16_t g, uint16_t b);
  void     write8 (uint8_t reg, uint32_t value);
  uint8_t  read8 (uint8_t reg);
  uint16_t read16 (uint8_t reg);
  void setInterrupt(boolean flag);
  void clearInterrupt(void);
  void setIntLimits(uint16_t l, uint16_t h);
  void     enable(void);


 private:
  boolean _tcs34725Initialised;
  tcs34725Gain_t _tcs34725Gain;
  tcs34725IntegrationTime_t _tcs34725IntegrationTime; 

  void     disable(void);
};


#endif
```

Here is the cpp file that I am using

```
/**************************************************************************/
/*!
    @file     Adafruit_TCS34725.cpp
    @author   KTOWN (Adafruit Industries)
    @license  BSD (see license.txt)


    Driver for the TCS34725 digital color sensors.


    Adafruit invests time and resources providing this open source code,
    please support Adafruit and open-source hardware by purchasing
    products from Adafruit!


    @section  HISTORY


    v1.0 - First release
*/
/**************************************************************************/
#include <avr/pgmspace.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>


#include "Adafruit_TCS34725.h"


/*========================================================================*/
/*                          PRIVATE FUNCTIONS                             */
/*========================================================================*/


/**************************************************************************/
/*!
    @brief  Implements missing powf function
*/
/**************************************************************************/
float powf(const float x, const float y)
{
  return (float)(pow((double)x, (double)y));
}


/**************************************************************************/
/*!
    @brief  Writes a register and an 8 bit value over I2C
*/
/**************************************************************************/
void Adafruit_TCS34725::write8 (uint8_t reg, uint32_t value)
{
  Wire.beginTransmission(TCS34725_ADDRESS);
  #if ARDUINO >= 100
  Wire.write(TCS34725_COMMAND_BIT | reg);
  Wire.write(value & 0xFF);
  #else
  Wire.send(TCS34725_COMMAND_BIT | reg);
  Wire.send(value & 0xFF);
  #endif
  Wire.endTransmission();
}


/**************************************************************************/
/*!
    @brief  Reads an 8 bit value over I2C
*/
/**************************************************************************/
uint8_t Adafruit_TCS34725::read8(uint8_t reg)
{
  Wire.beginTransmission(TCS34725_ADDRESS);
  #if ARDUINO >= 100
  Wire.write(TCS34725_COMMAND_BIT | reg);
  #else
  Wire.send(TCS34725_COMMAND_BIT | reg);
  #endif
  Wire.endTransmission();


  Wire.requestFrom(TCS34725_ADDRESS, 1);
  #if ARDUINO >= 100
  return Wire.read();
  #else
  return Wire.receive();
  #endif
}


/**************************************************************************/
/*!
    @brief  Reads a 16 bit values over I2C
*/
/**************************************************************************/
uint16_t Adafruit_TCS34725::read16(uint8_t reg)
{
  uint16_t x; uint16_t t;


  Wire.beginTransmission(TCS34725_ADDRESS);
  #if ARDUINO >= 100
  Wire.write(TCS34725_COMMAND_BIT | reg);
  #else
  Wire.send(TCS34725_COMMAND_BIT | reg);
  #endif
  Wire.endTransmission();


  Wire.requestFrom(TCS34725_ADDRESS, 2);
  #if ARDUINO >= 100
  t = Wire.read();
  x = Wire.read();
  #else
  t = Wire.receive();
  x = Wire.receive();
  #endif
  x <<= 8;
  x |= t;
  return x;
}


/**************************************************************************/
/*!
    Enables the device
*/
/**************************************************************************/
void Adafruit_TCS34725::enable(void)
{
  write8(TCS34725_ENABLE, TCS34725_ENABLE_PON);
  delay(3);
  write8(TCS34725_ENABLE, TCS34725_ENABLE_PON | TCS34725_ENABLE_AEN);  
}


/**************************************************************************/
/*!
    Disables the device (putting it in lower power sleep mode)
*/
/**************************************************************************/
void Adafruit_TCS34725::disable(void)
{
  /* Turn the device off to save power */
  uint8_t reg = 0;
  reg = read8(TCS34725_ENABLE);
  write8(TCS34725_ENABLE, reg & ~(TCS34725_ENABLE_PON | TCS34725_ENABLE_AEN));
}


/*========================================================================*/
/*                            CONSTRUCTORS                                */
/*========================================================================*/


/**************************************************************************/
/*!
    Constructor
*/
/**************************************************************************/
Adafruit_TCS34725::Adafruit_TCS34725(tcs34725IntegrationTime_t it, tcs34725Gain_t gain) 
{
  _tcs34725Initialised = false;
  _tcs34725IntegrationTime = it;
  _tcs34725Gain = gain;
}


/*========================================================================*/
/*                           PUBLIC FUNCTIONS                             */
/*========================================================================*/


/**************************************************************************/
/*!
    Initializes I2C and configures the sensor (call this function before
    doing anything else)
*/
/**************************************************************************/
boolean Adafruit_TCS34725::begin(void) 
{
  Wire.begin();

  /* Make sure we're actually connected */
  uint8_t x = read8(TCS34725_ID);
  Serial.println(x, HEX);
  if (x != 0x44)
  {
    return false;
  }
  _tcs34725Initialised = true;


  /* Set default integration time and gain */
  setIntegrationTime(_tcs34725IntegrationTime);
  setGain(_tcs34725Gain);


  /* Note: by default, the device is in power down mode on bootup */
  enable();


  return true;
}

/**************************************************************************/
/*!
    Sets the integration time for the TC34725
*/
/**************************************************************************/
void Adafruit_TCS34725::setIntegrationTime(tcs34725IntegrationTime_t it)
{
  if (!_tcs34725Initialised) begin();


  /* Update the timing register */
  write8(TCS34725_ATIME, it);


  /* Update value placeholders */
  _tcs34725IntegrationTime = it;
}


/**************************************************************************/
/*!
    Adjusts the gain on the TCS34725 (adjusts the sensitivity to light)
*/
/**************************************************************************/
void Adafruit_TCS34725::setGain(tcs34725Gain_t gain)
{
  if (!_tcs34725Initialised) begin();


  /* Update the timing register */
  write8(TCS34725_CONTROL, gain);


  /* Update value placeholders */
  _tcs34725Gain = gain;
}


/**************************************************************************/
/*!
    @brief  Reads the raw red, green, blue and clear channel values
*/
/**************************************************************************/
void Adafruit_TCS34725::getRawData (uint16_t *r, uint16_t *g, uint16_t *b, uint16_t *c)
{
  if (!_tcs34725Initialised) begin();


  *c = read16(TCS34725_CDATAL);
  *r = read16(TCS34725_RDATAL);
  *g = read16(TCS34725_GDATAL);
  *b = read16(TCS34725_BDATAL);

  /* Set a delay for the integration time */
  switch (_tcs34725IntegrationTime)
  {
    case TCS34725_INTEGRATIONTIME_2_4MS:
      delay(3);
      break;
    case TCS34725_INTEGRATIONTIME_24MS:
      delay(24);
      break;
    case TCS34725_INTEGRATIONTIME_50MS:
      delay(50);
      break;
    case TCS34725_INTEGRATIONTIME_101MS:
      delay(101);
      break;
    case TCS34725_INTEGRATIONTIME_154MS:
      delay(154);
      break;
    case TCS34725_INTEGRATIONTIME_700MS:
      delay(700);
      break;
  }
}


/**************************************************************************/
/*!
    @brief  Converts the raw R/G/B values to color temperature in degrees
            Kelvin
*/
/**************************************************************************/
uint16_t Adafruit_TCS34725::calculateColorTemperature(uint16_t r, uint16_t g, uint16_t b)
{
  float X, Y, Z;      /* RGB to XYZ correlation      */
  float xc, yc;       /* Chromaticity co-ordinates   */
  float n;            /* McCamy's formula            */
  float cct;


  /* 1. Map RGB values to their XYZ counterparts.    */
  /* Based on 6500K fluorescent, 3000K fluorescent   */
  /* and 60W incandescent values for a wide range.   */
  /* Note: Y = Illuminance or lux                    */
  X = (-0.14282F * r) + (1.54924F * g) + (-0.95641F * b);
  Y = (-0.32466F * r) + (1.57837F * g) + (-0.73191F * b);
  Z = (-0.68202F * r) + (0.77073F * g) + ( 0.56332F * b);


  /* 2. Calculate the chromaticity co-ordinates      */
  xc = (X) / (X + Y + Z);
  yc = (Y) / (X + Y + Z);


  /* 3. Use McCamy's formula to determine the CCT    */
  n = (xc - 0.3320F) / (0.1858F - yc);


  /* Calculate the final CCT */
  cct = (449.0F * powf(n, 3)) + (3525.0F * powf(n, 2)) + (6823.3F * n) + 5520.33F;


  /* Return the results in degrees Kelvin */
  return (uint16_t)cct;
}


/**************************************************************************/
/*!
    @brief  Converts the raw R/G/B values to color temperature in degrees
            Kelvin
*/
/**************************************************************************/
uint16_t Adafruit_TCS34725::calculateLux(uint16_t r, uint16_t g, uint16_t b)
{
  float illuminance;


  /* This only uses RGB ... how can we integrate clear or calculate lux */
  /* based exclusively on clear since this might be more reliable?      */
  illuminance = (-0.32466F * r) + (1.57837F * g) + (-0.73191F * b);


  return (uint16_t)illuminance;
}




void Adafruit_TCS34725::setInterrupt(boolean i) {
  uint8_t r = read8(TCS34725_ENABLE);
  if (i) {
    r |= TCS34725_ENABLE_AIEN;
  } else {
    r &= ~TCS34725_ENABLE_AIEN;
  }
  write8(TCS34725_ENABLE, r);
}


void Adafruit_TCS34725::clearInterrupt(void) {
  Wire.beginTransmission(TCS34725_ADDRESS);
  #if ARDUINO >= 100
  Wire.write(0x66);
  #else
  Wire.send(0x66);
  #endif
  Wire.endTransmission();
}




void Adafruit_TCS34725::setIntLimits(uint16_t low, uint16_t high) {
   write8(0x04, low & 0xFF);
   write8(0x05, low >> 8);
   write8(0x06, high & 0xFF);
   write8(0x07, high >> 8);
}
```

Comment: There's a load of code here, but C does not have the concept of classes. Perhaps this is C++ and you mistagged this?

Comment: No C compiler that I know of accepts `class Adafruit_TCS34725 { ... };`. If you are mixing C and C++ in your project, please say so.

Comment: The Arduino language is not really C. It uses the C language and adds a small subset of C++ for VERY simplistic classes. Thus, this isn't a mixture of C or C++, but rather something that is Arduino-specific.

Comment: To the author: First, I don't think you need that second `#include`, unless there is another file here with that name.

Comment: Yes you're right,  I meant c++.  Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0):

The [original example](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_TCS34725/blob/master/examples/tcs34725/tcs34725.pde) you modified compiles just fine. I'm pretty sure you get the error because you have not installed the library properly.

Assuming your sketchbook folder is:

`C:\Users\YourUserName\Documents\Arduino`

Then files `Adafruit_TCS34725.cpp` and `Adafruit_TCS34725.h` must be placed in, for example:

`C:\Users\YourUserName\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Adafruit_TCS34725`

If you were running Arduino IDE while placing those files, restart it. Last directory name can be different but it can contain only letters, underscores and digits. If you have downloaded this library from GitHub, chances are, folder name after extracting is `Adafruit_TCS34725-master`, this is invalid because it contains a `-`. If this is still unclear, there is a library installation tutorial [here](http://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-all-about-arduino-libraries-install-use/installing-a-library).

Other then that, in your modifications: `#include <Adafruit_TCS34725_CPP.h>` is unnecessary and you have two variables with name `tcs`, comment out (like in the original example) or remove one of them.

Comment: Thank you very much!! :)  I was able to get this working.  I had the libraries implemented wrong.